# Hierarchical list of MOC notes with dataview in Obsidian

Tags: obsidian-dataview

I have a library of notes in Obsidian sorted in hierarchical MOCs that link to each other.

For example, I have a note called "MOC_Data" which has links to various other MOCs

```
Home
    MOC_Data
        MOC_AI
            <notes about AI, ML and Deep Learning>
        MOC_BigQuery
            <notes about BigQuery setup and code>
        MOC_Databases
            ...
    MOC_Software
        MOC_Google Analytics
        MOC_Google Tag Manager
...
```

I want to use dataview to generate a hierarchical list of **only** the MOCs like so:

- MOC_Data

  - MOC_AI
  - MOC_BigQuery
  - MOC_Databases
- MOC_Software

  - MOC_Google Analytics
  - MOC_Google Tag Manager

But I don't know how to do that with dataview?

This gets me a list of all the MOCs, but not in a hierachical view

```
LIST
WHERE contains(file.name, "MOC_")
```